# Removing outliers from boxplot and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to create a plotly boxplot in R that doesnt show the outliers, and I found this link in the official page of plotly:
https://plot.ly/ggplot2/box-plots/#outliers

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(123)

df <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), size = 1000),]

p <- ggplot(df, aes(cut, price, fill = cut)) + 
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
ggtitle("Ignore outliers in ggplot2")

# Need to modify the plotly object and make outlier points have opacity equal 
to 0
p <- plotly_build(p)

p$data <- lapply(p$data, FUN = function(x){
 x$marker = list(opacity = 0)
 return(x)
})


# Create a shareable link to your chart
# Set up API credentials: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started
chart_link = plotly_POST(p, filename="geom_boxplot/outliers")
chart_link
```

The problem is that in their webpage and in my console, outliers are still being displayed.
[image]
Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: As the time passes, bug probably get fixed. `geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)` for me produces a box-plot without outliers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a typo. Maybe the example wasn't updated to account for some changes in the object structure. After calling `p <- plotly_build(p)`, we observe that there is no `p$data`, but there is `p$x$data`. So, changing the `lapply` call to the following:

```
p$x$data <- lapply(p$x$data, FUN = function(x){
 x$marker = list(opacity = 0)
 return(x)
})
```

makes everything work as intended:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make only outliers transparent, but actually all points transparent. With a geom_jitter layer, no points show up. I could only find `p$x$data$marker$outliercolor` regarding outliers setting, but doesn't work as expected. Do you have any idea if I want see the other points?

Comment: @SeanLin, any solution to ignore the outliers when using jitter?